# Adding containers and action bar to an Android Activity.

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, containers

I am trying to add action bar on top, and two containers below the action bar, each of the containers I want to have 80% of width and 20% of width.

Here is my XML file which is not working:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hany_action_bar.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="20"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="80"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: change `weightSum` for `weight`

Comment: Instead of `android:weightSum="20"/"80"` use `android:weight="20"/"80"`

Comment: weight is not a legal attribute here, not working means , i dont see my container neither on debug or in the graphical view

Comment: and then change your `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` with whatever `orientation` you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can try like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="com.example.hany_action_bar.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.6"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The math is wrong. 80% of 2 (the weightSum defined in the root container) is 1.6 not 1.8. Please do the math

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. Its not dangerously incorrect. Please dont downvote for this thing. Its a request.